# Código que exporta datos a Excel desde MYSQL, pero con caracteres raros

Tags: php, mysql

tengo una consulta en la que quizás me puedan ayudar, tengo este código PHP para realizar una consulta a una BD, y de ahí exportar el resultado de esa consulta a un excel:

```html
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["user_id"]) || $_SESSION["user_id"]==null){
 print "<script>alert(\"Acceso invalido!\");window.location='index.php';</script>";
}
  $user_id=$_SESSION["user_id"];
  $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'capacitaciones');
  mysqli_set_charset($mysqli,'utf8'); // para mostrar correctamente los acentos y las ñ 
?>

<?php
//Exportar datos de php a Excel
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel; charset=utf-8'" );
header("Expires: 0" );
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0" );
header("content-disposition: attachment;filename=reporte_capacitaciones.xls" );
?>
<HTML>
<TITLE>.: HOME :.</TITLE>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<?php
$NombreBD = "capacitaciones";
$Servidor = "localhost";
$Usuario = "root";
$Password ="";
$IdConexion = mysql_connect($Servidor, $Usuario, $Password);
$con = mysql_select_db($NombreBD, $IdConexion);

$sql="SELECT
  cursos.id_curso,
  cursos.codigo_sigper,
  cursos.id_ambito,
  ambito.ambito,
  DATE_FORMAT( jornadas_curso.fechas_curso, '%d-%m-%Y' ) As Fecha_Ejecucion,
  cursos.nombre_curso,
  relatores.nombre_relator,
  relatores.entidad_relator,
  relacion_curso_relator.id_relator                                           
  from cursos 
  inner join jornadas_curso on jornadas_curso.id_curso = cursos.id_curso
  inner join ambito on ambito.id_ambito = cursos.id_ambito
     inner join relacion_curso_relator on relacion_curso_relator.id_curso = cursos.id_curso
        inner join relatores on relatores.id_relator = relacion_curso_relator.id_relator
  and jornadas_curso.fechas_curso <= NOW()
  order by Fecha_Ejecucion DESC";  
$result=mysql_query($sql,$IdConexion);


?>

<TABLE BORDER=1 align="center" CELLPADDING=1 CELLSPACING=1>
<TR>

<TD bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><b>N° Identificador</b></TD>
<TD bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><b>Código SIGPER</b></TD>
<TD bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><b>Región</b></TD>
<TD bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><b>Ámbito Aprendizaje</b></TD>
<TD bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><b>Fecha de Ejecución</b></TD>
<TD bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><b>Nombre Curso</b></TD>
<TD bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><b>Nombre del Relator</b></TD>
<TD bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><b>Entidad Capacitadora</b></TD>

</TR>
<?php

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
printf("<tr>
<td>&nbsp;%s</td>
<td>&nbsp;%s&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;%s</td>
<td>&nbsp;%s</td>
<td>&nbsp;%s</td>
<td>&nbsp;%s</td>
<td>&nbsp;%s</td>
<td>&nbsp;%s</td>
</tr>", $row["id_curso"],"VII",$row["codigo_sigper"],$row["ambito"],$row["Fecha_Ejecucion"],$row["nombre_curso"],$row["nombre_relator"],$row["entidad_relator"]);
}
mysql_free_result($result);
mysql_close($IdConexion); //Cierras la Conexión
?>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

El problema esta en que, al exportar a excel, los nombres con acentos y Ñ me los muestras de manera extraña (algo así:  SISTEMA INFORMTICO DE APOYO AL MODELO DE INGRESO Y ASIGNACIӎ )

En la tabla ya tengo los campos como utf8_spanish_ci, no se que podría ser,

¿Que falta en el código para resolver los caracteres?

Muchas gracias por la ayuda

Comment: Cuando recorras las columnas prueba con utf8_encode: utf8_encode($row["nombre_curso"]);

Comment: Edgar, santo remedio, muchas gracias!!

Comment: Me alegra ayudar.